# How can I display a UILabel over a SKView?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uikit

I am looking to display a UILabel over the SKView I have created and displayed.  My end goal in this is to have the UILabel placed programmatically over the SKView that is being displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SKView` is a subclass of `UIView`, so you can just add a `UILabel` on top of it using `skView.addSubview(label)`.

Comment: Should I place this in my UIViewController class or my SKScene class?  The SKScene class is the one being displayed/viewed. I attempted creating a constant named skview that was equal to SKView().  I am not sure how else to approch this.

Comment: If you're using a `UILabel` instead of `SKLabelNode` for a reason, then probably better to display from the `UIViewController`.